# How to extract last ten elements of NSMutableArray (without predefined size) which has continuously varying objects in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've defined a `NSMutableArray` (but I haven't defined its size) which stores the continuous varying data. Is there any way to extract the last 10 elements of the `NSMutableArray` at any point of time?

Comment: Have you try something?

Comment: I tried using 'for loop', it's not working.

Comment: can not see any 'for loop' in your question. please add code what you've done.

Comment: To be clear, are you looking to REMOVE the last ten items or just pull them?  It is not clear whether you are trying to pop them from the stack when you say "extract".

Comment: Hi, I need to pull them off from the array and make a new array. My first array is a mutable array which has continuously varying(with time) objects.  Moreover, last 10 objects of first array at any point of time are the useful ones, so I want to extract them for analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can  follow two approaches the first one is -: manually introspect the array in for loop

NSMutableArray * arrayHavingTenOrMoreVaule = [[NSMutableArray    alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10",@"11", nil];

NSMutableArray * arrayHavingLessThenTenVaule = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"3",@"2",@"1", nil];

```
for (int k = 0 ; k<[[[arrayHavingTenOrMoreVaule reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects] count]; k++) {
    if (k<10) {
        NSLog(@"more%@",[[[arrayHavingTenOrMoreVaule reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects] objectAtIndex:k]);
    }
    if ([[[arrayHavingLessThenTenVaule reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects] count]>k && k<10) {
        NSLog(@"less%@",[[[arrayHavingLessThenTenVaule reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects] objectAtIndex:k]);
    }
}
```

And the second one is to use nsset i.e`    NSArray *tempArray = [[[arrayHavingTenOrMoreVaule reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects] subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 10)];
    NSLog(@"tempArray = %@",tempArray);

```
NSArray *tempArray2 = [[[arrayHavingLessThenTenVaule reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects] subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, [[[arrayHavingLessThenTenVaule reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects] count])];
NSLog(@"tempArray2 = %@",tempArray2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use following method,

```
 - (NSArray *)objectsAtIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes
```

Pass indexes last n-10 indexs it will return you a new array in which contains last 10 objects of your MutableArray.

```
NSIndexSet *lastTenIndexs = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange((theMutableArrayCount-10), theMutableArrayCount-1)];
NSArray *lastTenObjects = [theMutableArrayCount objectsAtIndexes:lastTenIndexs];
```

Other option use  `- (NSArray *)subarrayWithRange:(NSRange)range`

Answer (score 2):

You can use subarrayWithRange method to get the desired arraydata.
Try this hopefully it will work.

```
 if (yourMutableArray.count > 10) 
 {
 NSArray *newArray = [yourMutableArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(yourMutableArray.count-10, yourMutableArray.count-1)];
 }
```

Comment: Hi, I followed your suggestion, but it's not working. After running, it says ':terminating with uncaught exception of type NSExecption' and it shows 0 objects in 'newArray'.

Comment: NSRange does not take two indexes. The first item is index, the second item is count - so NSRangeMake(array.count-10, 10)